# Pass data to server side from Javascript code

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, http-headers

I'm trying to send data from client-side to server-side (asp.net c#), *if you really want to know, I want to send the `window.name` property*.

First I thought about having a `asp:HiddenField` and on the `OnSubmit` event have some JS write the value in the hidden field. The only problem is that I can access the hidden field value (according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)) only from `PreLoad` event to `PreRenderComplete` event. The project that I'm working on has a lot of code in the `OnInit` event, and unfortunately I cannot move it and I need to use the `window.name` value here.

The other ideas that I have is to add a custom HTTP Header `windowId` or on the `OnSubmit` event have a JS that appends a parameter to the `document.location.href`.

I managed to write to the header from JS with the `XMLHttpRequest` `setRequestHeader`, but, *maybe I did something wrong in my implementation*, this generates 2 requests, the first one is the normal, expected one(clicking a button/link ...) and the second is from the `XMLHttpRequest`. I find this behavior very unnatural. ***Do you have any sugestions?*** (*see code snippet below*). **I do not what to use AJAX.**

```
    var oReq = new window.XMLHttpRequest;
    oReq.open('POST', document.location, false);
    oReq.setRequestHeader("windowId", window.name);
    oReq.send(null);
```

For the `OnSubmit` hook idea, i haven't spent to much time on it, but i think I have to append the # character before i append my `windowId` parameter with it's value, so that the page doesn't reload. I might be wrong about this. Any way, I have to remove this from the URL after I take the value, so that the user doesn't see the nasty URL. ***Do you have any sugestions?***

**Ok so what are your ideas?**

Thank you for reading all my blabbering, and thank you, in advance, for you answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the `<asp:HiddenField />` (e.g., `<asp:HiddenField ID="hfWindowName" runat="server" />`. In `OnInit` you can still access its value by using `Request.Form`:

```
string windowName = Request.Form(hfWindowName.UniqueID);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've forgot about Request.Form.

Comment: This didn't work for me. In Oninit, we don't have the access to the control values. It gives me NULL everytime..